# Is it possible to bind configuration to stateless/readonly model in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Normally, we would have some model

```
public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public string Sql { get; set; }
    public string NoSql { get; set; }
}
```

then we have something in `appsettings.json` as follow:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Sql": "some connection string",
    "NoSql": "some other connection string"
}
```

Then I bind the model as follows:

```
services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(
            options => Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Bind(options));
```

All works perfectly, but it doesn't make sense for my model to be mutable since it is holding important information. After all, configurations are static information, so once my model is read, it should stay like it is.

Is there any other way of doing this more safely?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As an alternative, for [version 2.1+](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/394), you can now bind to non-public properties by specifying to do so with [`BinderOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binderoptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1):

```
services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(options => 
        Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")
                .Bind(options, c => c.BindNonPublicProperties = true));
```

or to just get them:

```
var connectionStrings = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")
        .Get<ConnectionStrings>(c => c.BindNonPublicProperties = true);
```

Comment: Doesn't this require the property to be like `public string Sql { get; private set; }` instead of just `public string Sql { get; }` ? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.binderoptions.bindnonpublicproperties?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) states "If true, the binder will attempt to set all non read-only properties." which seems to exclude read-only properties as the OP is describing.

Comment: @Dai Yes that is true and probably should have been mentioned thanks. This answers "Is there any other way of doing this more safely?" from the original post as the property can at least have `private set;`. But it is still not readonly as you brought out.

Answer (score 5):

code like this uses underhood the `ConfigurationBinder` that expects public properties. From [BindProperty method](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L104-L110):

```
// We don't support set only, non public, or indexer properties
if (property.GetMethod == null ||
   !property.GetMethod.IsPublic ||
   property.GetMethod.GetParameters().Length > 0)
{
   return;
}
```

As a workaround, I may suggest populating your class manually.  Take the following as an example:

```
public class ConnectionStrings
{
    public ConnectionStrings(string sql, string noSql)
    {
        Sql = sql;
        NoSql = noSql;
    }

    public string Sql { get; private set; }
    public string NoSql { get; private set; }
}
```

and then in `ConfigureServices` method:

```
var sqlValue = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:Sql", string.Empty);
var noSqlValue = Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStringsApp:NoSql", string.Empty);

services.Configure<ConnectionStrings>(
           options => new ConnectionStrings(sqlValue, noSqlValue));
```

Comment: Great, I will do that , thanks! Just one thing, I'd rather make properties without setter and set them in constructor to simulate full readonly behavior since leaving them with private set implies that this same class might change them again later, while I want to be very explicit that this is readonly property. :)

Answer (score -2):

My implementation has a config file for each environment, and a second config file that stores options for all environments. Connection Strings are stored alongside other options in a different section. I use the following methodology to load both Config files, then later attach my Connection String directly to the DbContext.

I've sliced out the irrelevant parts of the code.

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public class Startup
{
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        // Add MVC, Authorization, etc.
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnection")));
    }
}
```

appsettings.production.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnection": "Data Source=mydb.myserver.com;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sqluser;Password=sqlpwd;"
  }
  "Settings": {
    "Setting1": "Value1"
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't at all what was asked. He wants the properties of the configuration class to not be able to change after they've been set.

Comment: He wants to load Connection Strings. I illustrated that you don't need to build a Model class to store the information, and by using Dependency Injection, none of your code outside of Startup ever has to care about the Connection String. I demonstrated how to load the configuration without binding it to a mutable model.

Comment: Not to mention, right there in the code I have the Configuration object with `private set` so it can't be modified outside of Startup. You can then use DI to stick your Configuration into whichever Controllers you want. Does that still not answer the question on how to load Configuration? Everyone on SO is so eager to downvote and contribute nothing positive. It's why I lurked here for years before finally registering.

Comment: `{ get; private set; }` does not _indicate-intent_ the same way that `{ get; }` does.