# Config Values are null when trying to access them using GetSection in startup file.(IOptions-config retrieval)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, config

I'm not able to receive the config values from appsettings file in .NET Core.

**appsettings.json**:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "PortedConfig": {
    "ConfigTableAccess": "ConfigTableConnectionString",
    "ConfigTableName": "Config"
  }
}
```

**startup.cs**:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();
    var config = Configuration;
    var settings = Configuration.GetSection("PortedConfig").Get<PortedConfig>();
    services.Configure<PortedConfig>(options => Configuration.GetSection("PortedConfig").Bind(options));
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddScoped<IEncryptManager, EncryptManager>()
            .AddScoped<IDecryptManager, DecryptManager>();
}
```

**PortedConfig.cs**:

```
public class PortedConfig
{
    public string ConfigTableAccess;
    public string ConfigTableName;
}
```

In `startup.cs`, at runtime the configuration is getting populated but when I use `GetSection` the values are null as shown in images below:

[image: Screenshot of Configuration]
[image: Screenshot of Configuration]

As you can see in images above `ConfigTableAccess` and `ConfigTableName` are null in settings variable.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872120/configuration-getsection-returns-null-value-for-object-sections/53873699#53873699

Comment: Since .NET Core 2.1 you can bind properties with private setter - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54711906/968003

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the fields to properties and don't forget a public setter.

```cs
public class PortedConfig
{
    public string ConfigTableAccess { get; set; }
    public string ConfigTableName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This actually worked. So just by setting the access modifier to public, the property exposed to references in other classes cannot be modified. Can you please explain why this behavior occurs and why we need to specify the getter and setter?.

Comment: This is how the ASP.NET team wrote their ConfigurationBinder - using reflection to find properties with a public setter. Your original fields were public, but were still `fields` and fields are not properties.